# jQuery: using a variable as a substitute for a div?

Tags: jquery

**Ooops, fiddle updated now correct**
In this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/SySRb/118/  once you click `.start` an element from an array is randomly chosen and assigned to variable `ran`  This random selection jquery has been checked http://jsfiddle.net/urfXq/96/ and is working so I don't think that's the problem, although people have suggested ways to make it more elegant.

Continuing on...

After the element from the array is assigned to `ran`, an if- then structure begins. The `if` is definitely false in this fiddle, so  the `else` code should run. My intent with the else code is to add the div hash tag, and then do ran.show so that one of the two divs (hidden with css) on the page becomes visible.

The else isn't working. If the if statement were true, I assume it wouldn't work either...

```
else { 
                  ran = ('# + ran');
                  $('ran').show(); //one of the two divs should show but they don't
                  }

          });
```

Note, because this is just a piece of larger code, if you totally restructure everything, I may not be able to use it...

Comment: @mu is too short  sorry I updated OP with correct fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the string concatenation wrong..

use

```
ran = '#' + ran;
$(ran).show();
```

and you need to call your `test` method on `document.ready` so use

```
$(test);
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/SySRb/129/

Comment: thanks, did you put in the console.(logs) just for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. You're forgetting to use `$` to query the DOM with jQuery. You should replace:

   ```
   ran = ('# + ran');
   ```

   with

   ```
   ran = $("#" + ran");
   ```

   That is, build a jQuery selector by appending `#` to `ran`, then  call jQuery with that selector.
2. Since the variable you're saving the results of the jQuery call is called `ran`, you should replace

   ```
   $('ran').show();
   ```

   with

   ```
   ran.show();
   ```
3. Does the function `test()` ever get called? Part of the reason you're code isn't working is because that function is not getting called, so the click event is never bound. Wrap the entire thing in `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` and call `test()`.
4. Be sure to use `var` with your variable declarations. Otherwise, you're creating a global variable.

Here's your example fixed up: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/9BcUP/

Comment: thanks a lot. someone answered before you so I have to give them the accepted answer, but I really appreciate this and will learn from it.

Comment: @Michael: No problem! Just glad you got it figured out quickly `:)`